# Trying to use Kotlin-gradle plugin from local url

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm trying to setup the gradle-kotlin-plugin locally, but it doesnt work at all. Im using Gradle 4.9 and Kotlin version 1.2.71. The Gradle sync fails and this exceptions is thrown:

```
org/jetbrains/kotlin/cli/common/PropertiesKt

NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/cli/common/PropertiesKt
```

Im put all needed resources into the directory /lib/kotlin, meaning kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.71.jar, kotlin-stdlib-1.2.70.jar,kotlin-stdlib-1.2.70.pom,kotlin-stdlib-common-1.2.70.jar,kotlin-stdlib-common-1.2.70.pom.
If i set the repo to  url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" everything is working fine(i always want to load the plugin from the local file and NOT from the online repo).
The other kotlin dependencies are also included.

build.gradle

```
 buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
        repositories {
        flatDir dirs: '/lib/kotlin'
        mavenLocal()
        maven{
            url uri('lib/kotlin')
        }
 dependencies {

        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"


    }
    ...
    allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'application'
    apply plugin: "kotlin"
    ..
    dependencies {
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
```

Edit:
Now the plugin is working but Kotlin is not compiling and is telling me:

```
  Could not perform incremental compilation: Could not connect to Kotlin compile daemon
Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below dependency also

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
```

Do clean your ~/.gradle directory

Comment: i followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34181002/kotlin-and-gradle-without-maven-central?rq=1 approach und got a NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics Exception